# How can I edit a pinmux for BeagleBone Black on linux kernel 3.18?

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack

I have just upgraded my kernel from 3.8.13 to 3.18 and need to control the pinmux options on the bbb. I understand that there is no cape manager anymore and i have used the following command to set the pin P8_10 to be a GPIO with pull down enabled. echo gpio_pd > /sys/devices/ocp./P8_10_pinmux./state

My issue arises when i try and use the same command for P8_26. I am able to set this pin to be a GPIO or to the default state but it does not recognise the gpio_pd or gpio_pu command.

The following answer has provided me a good deal of information and been very helpful:

[How can I edit a pinmux for BeagleBone Black on linux kernel 3.17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892485/how-can-i-edit-a-pinmux-for-beaglebone-black-on-linux-kernel-3-17/28263310#28263310)

Can anyone point out what i am missing here?

Thanks in advance